# File loader in wpf

Tags: wpf, file, import

Is there any file loader control in WPF which allows importing files during the runtime?
(choosing any file from the file system).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "importing" them? Import them to where and from where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are  you looking for something like the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx)?  If so, there are examples of how to use it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2010/03/26/openfiledialog-sample.aspx) or [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/236/) or you can google "wpf openfiledialog" and find many others.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Forms OpenFileDialog controls are still available for WPF apps:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/aa21c4b6-aa44-44e0-82c9-6e29d9e3c2e3/

I have mostly seen apps using the win forms dialog or an updated win forms one. For example:
http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/

As a side note, the silverlight file upload picker for SharePoint 2010 looks pretty good it would be good if MS released that to the wild. :)